# iCloud backups stopped working on our home network

Tags: icloud

Several months ago, iCloud backups from our iPhones and iPad stopped working on our home network. We get the "last backup could not be completed" message. The backups work on other networks. I thought it might be a problem with our DSL router, but I replaced it and still have the same problem. iCloud Drive works fine.

Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Comment: You could try contacting your ISP, but they don't tend to be the most helpful of folk. I'm betting they botched something up.

Comment: iCloud Backup uses the 443 TCP port [1]; I doubt your ISP blocked it because it's used for SSL, (https, email, among others), and you probably would have noticed that before.    [1]: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202944

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I'll try to talk to the ISP again. I'm sure 443 isn't blocked since all other iCloud services work - Pages docs stored in iCloud, for instance. Calendar and Notes synch OK too, I see from the much appreciated table you linked to that these services also rely on 443.